# Adding li element only if it not already there?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am constructing an `<li>` element like this:

```
var element = $("<li></li>") 
    .html(mHTML)  
    .attr('id', "elemid");
```

I am trying to add this element to a `<ul>` element only if it doesn't already exist. Any ideas on how to do this? Am I supposed to use `contains()` to see if the `ul` element contain the html and then decide? For instance,

```
<ul id="elemul">
  <li id="elemli1">Element 1</li>
  <li id="elemli2">Element 2</li>
  <li id="elemli3">Element 3</li>
</ul>
```

If I try adding Element 1, it should not add it. What should I do if its a longer string (not really long but about 150 characters).

**Note: I cannot rely on IDs to determine the uniqueness.** i.e. I might end up forming something like: `<li id="elemli3">Element 1</li>`

Do I go about using hashmaps?

Comment: @Delan: Thanks for fixing the tag. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!$('#elemul li:contains("Element 1")').length)
{
    $('#elemul').append($('li').attr('id', 'elemli1').text('Element 1'));
}
```

Comment: This is correct according to the OP's request. Unfortunately, `contains` is close to useless in most cases. It is case sensitive, and you cannot limit it to an whole match; `li:contains("Element 1")` will also get `<li>Element 100</li>`. It is probably better to hold this data in a variable, not in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a jQuery user, so bear with me. However, the native JavaScript can be turned into jQuery code quite easily.

```
if (!document.getElementById('elemli1')) {
  var elemli1 = document.createElement('li');
  elemli1.id = 'elemli1';
  document.getElementById('elemul').appendChild(elemli1);
}
```

If you want to create an element if there are no list items in the list at all, replace the if expression with:

```
!document.getElementById('elemul').childNodes.length
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Sorry that I wasn't clear. The content could come in with a different ID in my case. Just updated my post.

Comment: OK then. Updated my post to have a possibly more helpful answer.

Comment: +1 for the tip Delan. I am learning jQuery now so I was looking for a more jQuerish approach :) Thanks for your time.